# Not able to get default value on submit button in info map window html form used ng-init to assign default value in the controller

Tags: html, angularjs, ionic-framework

Below is my **html code**:

```
        var contentString = '<form> <div class="list card"> ' +
         ' <label class="item item-input item-floating-label">'+
         '<input type="text" id="username" ng-minlength="5" ng-maxlength="20" ng-model="push.username" ng-init="push.username='+locations[i][4]+'">'+ 
         '</label>'+
       '  <button class="button button-block button-positive" ng-click="sendRequestDriver(push)">Request Driver</button>' +
    ' </label>' +
      ' </div> </form>';
var compiled = $compile(contentString)($scope);
```

My **controller code**:

```
.controller('RequestDriver', ['$scope', '$state', '$ionicHistory', function ($scope, $state, $ionicHistory) {
    $scope.push = {};
    $scope.sendRequestDriver = function (push) {
        console.log(push);
    };
}])
```

But when I clicked on request driver I get undefined value.

Answer (score 0):

The issue is solved by using  `ng-value` instead of `ng-init`